# How to pull strings from multiple .txt files based on file name and append them to a new file?

Tags: powershell

so basically I have a series of .txt files following the same nomenclature, such as:

```
1111210803_3CE_080977851__006908818__21110300013442021110420211105_20211110_120447_35418862_820

1111210933_3CE_006908818__2111040001442021110520211108_20211110_120447_35418860_820
```

The naming convention on these all files always starts with the date, ie `111121`. Inside these files, you have lines of strings. I am interested in pulling a specific string in the first line from each of these files. Here is an example of the first line:

```
123456789012345678901234567890123 I             696969CCHKCTX       12345678901   DA 22758287
```

In particular, I am interested in the `696969CCHKCTX` string. All files will have some numbers followed by the `CCHKCTX` value. I want to pull the `696969` part of the `696969CCHKCTX` string from each .txt file and append them all into a new file.

If possible, I would like to sum those strings and add the appropriate decimal place, as they are to actually be dollar values ie `696969` is actually representing `6969.69` and the last two numbers in that string always represent the cent amount. This rule applies to all the .txt files. I want to be able to apply this to all files that are the same date (ie all files starting with `111121`)

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, which combines [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object), and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), as well as the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | # get files of interest; add path / filter as needed.
  Group-Object { $_.Name.Substring(0, 6) } | # group by shared date prefix
    ForEach-Object {
      $firstLines = $_.Group | Get-Content -First 1 # get all 1st lines
      # Extract the cents amounts and sum them.
      $sumCents = 0.0
      $firstLines.ForEach({ 
        $sumCents += [double] ($_ -replace '.+\b(\d+)CCHKCTX\b.+', '$1') 
      })
      # Output an object with the date prefix and the sum dollar amount.
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Date = $_.Name
        Sum = $sumCents / 100
      }
    }
```

The above outputs a table-formatted representation to the display. You can save it to a file with `>` / [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file), for instance, though it's better to use a *structured* text format for later processing, such as [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv).